# change from display name when sending mail from postfix

Tags: postfix

I have this script which runs as root, and when it fails to do something it needs to send a mail using postfix (actually the regular mail command on Centos5).

The problem is that the "from" user in the email is "root", how can I change it to another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using postfix, use the postfix sendmail drop-in:

```
echo "this is the mail" | sendmail -F "Bogus User" -f bogususer@some.net recipient@destination.address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new user on the system, and run the "mail" command using that user:

```
 su foo -c "echo blabla | mail foo@bar"
```

Comment: This is crazy and stupid. But then again, you are answering yourself, which means you probably are crazy. It might work.

Comment: Not only is the syntax and flag for su wrong, this is a terrible idea (from a security perspective, at least).

Comment: Now it's "only" a terrible idea. From every point of view ;-)